# Microsoft Graph API /me 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Here's my relevant code...

```
Dim wclient2 = New WebClient()
wclient2.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
Dim response As String = wclient2.DownloadString("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
```

I'm getting "400 Bad Request" error.

My `accessToken` is valid.  My application is registered and has User.Read.All application permissions.

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the error returned in the response body?

Comment: Did you try adding the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`?

Comment: @Filburt yes I tried that first.  Took it out not knowing for sure if the response was in fact JSON.

Comment: @DanSilver "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: @Filburt same error message with `wclient2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")`

Comment: [Bad Request 400 when making API call to Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43332236/205233) suggests that an `Accept` header is required as well. `WebClient` and `WebRequest` an the like all behave a little different in one or the other way.

Comment: @Filburt I tried `wclient2.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")` and `wclient2.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8")` and got the same 400 Bad Request error message.

Comment: i tried  `Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
            wr.Method = "GET"
            wr.KeepAlive = True
            wr.ContentType = "appication/json"
            wr.Accept = "application/json"
            wr.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
            
            Dim res As HttpWebResponse
            res = DirectCast(wr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            
            Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream())
            Dim gMe As String = sr.ReadToEnd` still get 400 error

Comment: @s15199d Please turn on Fiddler and get all the request+response headers and the body and provide that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application permissions are only applied when using the OAuth Client Credentials grant. This grant authenticates your *app*, not a user. In other words, there isn't a "user" in context.

The `/me` URI is just a shorthand alias for `/users/{currentlyAuthenticatedUser}`. Since you don't have a user authenticated, the Graph has no idea who `/me` is referring to.

When using Client Credentials, you need to explicitly reference the user you want:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName | id}
```

Comment: Looks like I need to be using OpenID Connect. So, I'm barking up the wrong tree.  Thanks @MarcLaFleur !

Comment: You could also use the Authorization Code or Implicit Grants (OpenID Connect is basically a superset of Auth Code).